# Can I create a package with root directory?

Tags: python

Assume the project directory structure is below:

```
test-package:
  __init__.py
  hello.py
  setup.py
```

And the setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="test-package",

    packages=find_packages(),
    version="1.0",

    include_package_data=True,
)
```

'test-package' is the root directory of the project. Then do:

```
pip install .
```

In the site-packages directory, there is only:

```
test_package-1.0-py3.7.egg-info/
```

I can't see the source file 'hello.py'.

I know most python projects's package name is not the root directory of the project. But in case I want to create a root directory name as the package name like this, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a parent folder for test-package and put setup.py in there also use underscores for the package name.  Technically PEP8 recommends all lowercase with no underscores for package names, but it's not a strict recommendation.

```
my-project:
  setup.py
  test_package:
    __init__.py
    hello.py
```

this has a helpful tutorial: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Edit: package name should use underscores not dashes

Comment: Is `-` valid inside a package name? I thought you'd need an underscore there.

Comment: Ah I missed that!

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly my question. Is it possible that the package name can be the root directory name?

Comment: there's 2 things that will cause problems with the install and usage. First the setup.py being in the package directory is not the standard. It's possible you could make this work but you'd be violating a convention that's universally used for basically no gain. Also the dashes being in the package name is a problem

Comment: I fixed the 'dash' problem. How to make this work, in case I want it this way? I have a reason for that, namely making the root as the package name.